# Type error when mocking Slick Query using ScalaMock: what does "some other" mean?

Tags: eclipse, scala, mocking, slick

I have used Java for several years, however I'm new to Scala and am still trying to figure out its type system.  I'm using Scala 2.10.2, Slick 1.0.1, and ScalaMock 2.10-3.0-M4 in Eclipse Scala IDE 3.0.1

I'm trying to mock out [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) in `updateNameById` using [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/).

```
def updateNameById(id: Int, input: String, users: RichTable[Object]) = {
    users.where(_.id === id).map{ e => e.test }.update(input)
}

abstract class RichTable[T](name: String = "blank") 
        extends slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Table[T](name) {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def test = column[String]("test")
}
```

(I'm actually passing in users: RichTable[User] where User has a complex inheritance hierarchy, but I've temporarily removed the uses of User to simplify the example)

`users.where` returns a `scala.slick.lifted.Query`, so I try to mock this out as follows

```
class ModelTest extends FlatSpec with MockFactory {
    def test = {
        val mockUsers = mock[RichTable[Object]]
        // mockQuery definition
        val mockQuery = mock[scala.slick.lifted.Query[RichTable[Object],
            scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]]
        (mockUsers.where _).expects(*).returns(mockQuery)
        Main.updateNameById(1, "asdf", mockUsers)
    }
}
```

The mockQuery definition gives me these cryptic type errors

```
type mismatch;
found : scala.slick.lifted.Query[O(in method union),
    scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]
required: scala.slick.lifted.Query[(some other)O(in method union),
    scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]

type mismatch;
found : scala.slick.lifted.Query[O(in method unionAll),
    scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]
required: scala.slick.lifted.Query[(some other)O(in method unionAll),
    scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]
```

I have no idea what "O(in method union[all])" vs. "(some other)O(in method union[All])" means, and Google hasn't been any help (it doesn't help matters that "some other" is an extremely generic phrase - googling "scala some other type error" produces pretty much the same results as "scala type error").  Does anybody know what this means and/or how to fix the type error?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer?